# how to resolve out of index error on incremental condition in a for loop?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of `dispatch` whose values are in decimals. Now I want to form two lists from this `dispatch`:

1. Charge
2. Discharge

   `dispatch = [0.39, 0.81, 0.58, 0.19, 0.70, 0.75, 0.66, 0.10, 0.58, 0.65, 0.87, 0.86, 0.38, 0.31, 0.63,]`

Now there is condition for `charge` and `discharge`:

- Charge = If dispatch[0] is less than dispatch[1] then it means charge and its value will greater minus smaller value.
- Discharge = If dispatch[0] is greater than dispatch[1] then it means discharge and its value will be greater minus smaller value.
  My attempt:

  `discharge = [(dispatch[i] - dispatch[i+1]) if dispatch[i] > dispatch[i+1] else 0 for i in range(0,  len(dispatch))]`

  `charge = [(dispatch[i+1] - dispatch[i]) if dispatch[i] < dispatch[i+1] else 0 for i in range(0,  len(dispatch))]`

But in this logic, there is an **INCREMENTA**L condition `i+1`, which will give the error of `list out of index` that I know of but I don't know the solution for this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: And what should happen with `charge` when you reach the last item? You only process up to next to last (-> shorten your range). Or perform other action? Assume value, use last value twice?

Comment: That was  the problem actually when it will reach the last item it will give an error of list out of index. There is no special condition for the last item. Its simple that you have to compare the element to next element of the list to check for discharge or charge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `range(0,  len(dispatch))` to `range(0,  len(dispatch) - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace:

```
range(0, len(dispatch))
```

with

```
range(len(dispatch)-1)
```

First thing, you actually do not need the `0` within `range`, this is the default behaviour.

Secondly, you just need to iterate until the second last item, to evaluate `(dis)charge`.

---

### Alternative approach:

A more pythonic way of getting the desired result would be to use `zip` and `list slicing`:

```
discharge = [max(0, a-b) for a,b in zip(dispatch[:-1], dispatch[1:])]
charge = [max(0, b-a) for a,b in zip(dispatch[:-1], dispatch[1:])]
```